# Classify the irreducible representations of a group which has a cyclic subgroup of index 2 with some condition

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group which has a cyclic subgroup $C$ of index $2$. Suppose there exists an element $g\notin C$ such that $gcg^{-1}=c^{-1}$ for all $c\in C$. Classify the irreducible representations of $G$.

---

I would be glad if someone could check my attempt. I know that there is a bijection between the conjugacy classes of $G$ and irreducible representations of $G$. Any comment would be appreciated.

**Attempt**. Let $\pi$ be any irreducible representation of $G$.

1. Pick any irreducible subrepresentation $\rho$ of $res_C^G(\pi)$.
2. By Frobenius reciprocity theorem, we have $\langle\pi,Ind_C^G(\rho)\rangle=\langle res_C^G(\pi),\rho \rangle$
3. But, $\langle res_C^G(\pi),\rho \rangle$ is a positive integer since $\rho$ is a subrepresentation of $res_C^G(\pi)$.
4. Since $\langle\pi,Ind_C^G(\rho)\rangle$ is a positive integer, $\pi$ is a subrepresentation of $Ind_C^G(\rho)$.
5. So, $\dim\pi\leq \dim Ind_C^G(\rho)=[G:C]\dim \rho=2$ since any irreducible representation of an abelian group is one-dimensional.

So, any irreducible representation of $G$ has dimension 1 or 2. Thanks!

Comment: @SeanEberhard:  The group $G$ does not have to be dihedral, the simplest counterexample being the quaternion group $Q_8 = \{\pm 1, \pm i, \pm j, \pm k\}$.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Oops, you are right. Actually $G$ is either dihedral or generalized quaternion (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion_group#Generalized_quaternion_group). Indeed, since $g^2 \in C$ we have $g^2 = g(g^2)g^{-1} = g^{-2}$, so $g^4 = 1$ and the order of $g$ is ether $2$ (dihedral) or $4$ (generalized quaternion).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have said so far is correct but there is a lot of work to do still. You have correctly observed that every irreducible representation of $G$ is a constituent of a representation induced from an irreducible representation of $C$.

1. What are the irreducible representations of $C$?
2. What are the corresponding induced representations of $G$?
3. Which of those are irreducible? (Hint: compute $\langle \chi,\chi\rangle$.)
4. Of those which are not irreducible, try to determine how they decompose. (Hint: The constituents will be one-dimensional, and therefore they are representations of $G / G' \cong C_2 \times C_2$.)
5. (strictly speaking optional) Check you have all the representations by computing $\sum_\chi \chi(1)^2$.